# how to make "nicer" Access Forms in 2016?

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-office

The file is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3FvBqE2BCLXS3ZJTU5sbGRIODA/view?usp=sharing).

I am very new to access. Here is what I already have
[image]

I want to make it nicer, which has the following look:
[image]

Difficulties are:

1 - The checkbox is too small. Can't make them larger.
2 - Even in the design view, I can't find an easier way to align the cells.
3 - When using the form to input data, can we make the font size bigger?

Many thanks!

Comment: (1) I have not tried this, but here is a link to something that will let you fake larger checkboxes: http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/Bigger-Checkbox-t1252269.html&hl=checkbox  
(2) If your layout is static (or can the # of checkboxes vary), you should be able to align (if in Design View); otherwise if the names have a pattern, you could use VBA code to move the boxes to any place/spacing you want;
  (3) Is your question really "I want to display data at font size 'x', but if allowing edits, I want to use font size 'y'?

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn This may be a stupid question. But I just dont think it is easy enough to design a "nice" table in Access as it would be in Word/Excel. Even in Design View, it looks so ugly. And not that easy to zoom in/out. Not even changing the font/size style ect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything you can do in Excel, you can do in Access.  It's all a matter of skill level and attention to detail.  That being said, there *are* certain limitations.

There is only 1 size for a checkbox.  If you want it bigger, you have to create a textbox with some OnClick code behind it.  You would then have to have some code to translate this back to Yes/No data.  You can probably do something like:

```
Private Sub MyField_OnClick
  If MyField.Text = "" Then
    MyField.Text = "X"
  Else
    MyField.Text = ""
  End If
End Sub
```

This will set the field to either "X" (checked) or "" (unchecked).  There are probably other ways to do this as well, such as making it an OLE control and swapping out images of a checked and unchecked box, depending on the last active value.

Aligning cells is easy, it's a formatting issue.  Select all your controls (which you can do by selecting one control, hold the Ctrl key down and then select additional controls with the key still pressed), right-click and choose Align from the menu.  Done.

And yes, you can make the font size anything you want.  Just expand the textbox a little to fit the font, go into the textbox's Property window and change the font name, size and/or weight.

Answer (score 2):

You can't make the check box larger ***but*** the label associated with the check box is clickable so the user has a bigger target to click on. You can align cells in the form designer by changing the x/y properties of the cells as a group -- select the desired cells, open the properties window, and change the desired properties.